# How can I submit a form in a php file through VueJS (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, vue.js

I have a PHP file that contains a form and a table and looks something like this:

```
printf ("<form action=\"%s\" method=post>", $PHP_SELF); //this is the url
printf ("<input type=hidden name=user_id value=\"%s\">", $user_id);
printf ("<input type=hidden name=holiday_year_id value=\"%s\">", $holiday_year_id); 
printf ("<input type=\"text\" size=9 name=holiday_taken_from_date  value=\"%s\">", $from_date);
printf ("<input type=\"text\" size=9 name=holiday_taken_to_date  value=\"%s\">", $to_date);
printf ("<input type=submit name=submit_request_holiday_dates value=Submit>")
echo "</form>";
```

One key point is this line:

```
printf ("<input type=submit name=submit_request_holiday_dates value=Submit>")
```

When the form is currently submitted, a variable called `$submit_request_holiday_dates` is set by this line.  When the page reloads this variable is caught in an IF statement and the next screen in the process is presented to the user.

**My Problem**

I have rebuilt this form in Vue as part of modernising the app.

My intention is to use my new Vue form which I have injected into the php page, and hide the old inline table which is being displayed via 'echo`.  This will enable me to continue to use all the old PHP logic whilst modernising the app.

```
this.url,
this.userId,
this.holidayYear,
this.fromDate,
this.toDate
```

How can I write a method for my new Submit button (Vue) that takes my Vue values above and populates the PHP form at the top of the screen with them and then submits the PHP form?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof of concept that can help.
Let's say this is your Vue form app:

```
var newForm = new Vue({
  el: '#new-form',
  data: {
    fromDate: null,
    toDate: null,
    oldForm: null
  },
  mounted:function(){
    /* when mounted, get old Php form */
    this.oldForm = document.forms[0]; // depends on how your html is structured
    /* hide old form */
    this.oldForm.style.display = "none";
    /* copy old form data */
    this.fromDate = this.oldForm.holiday_taken_from_date.value;
    this.toDate = this.oldForm.holiday_taken_to_date.value;
    /* etc... */
  },
  methods:{
    sendForm: function(){
      /* let's say this is the method invoked by the Vue form on submit */
      /* update old PHP form */
      this.oldForm.holiday_taken_from_date.value = this.fromDate;
      this.oldForm.holiday_taken_to_date.value = this.toDate;
      /* then submit the old form */
      this.oldForm.submit();
    }
  }
});
```

Basically, your Vue method just uses vanilla JS to update and [submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) the old form.